# Mapping through Object that is passed to child as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I am trying to map through an object that is passed as prop and want to display different HTML elements for different object values

Object;

```
         const allDesc =  {description: "Title Description", description1: "Intro 
    Description", description3:"Sub title", description3: "Sub Description"}
```

Code:

```
      <div>
        {Object.keys(allDesc).map((desc, index) => {
          if (allDes[desc] !== "") {
            return (
              <>
                <h1>allDesc.description</h1>
                <p>allDesc.description1</p>
                <h3>allDesc.description2</h3>
                <p>allDesc.description3</p>
              </>
            );
          }
        })}
      </div>
```

This approach displays nothing, what would be the correct approach for mapping through an object and displaying different HTML elements for different object values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` over the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries). If the key matches "description" return the value as an `<h1>`, otherwise return the value as a `<p>`.

```js
function Example({ allDesc }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(allDesc).map(([key, value]) => {
        if (key === 'description') return <h1>{value}</h1>;
        if (key === 'description3') return <h3>{value}</h3>;
        return <p>{value}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const allDesc = {description: 'Title Description', description1: 'Intro Description', description3: 'Another Description', description4: 'More text' };

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example allDesc={allDesc} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: What would be the approach if I have description3 as well in the object and make description2 an <h3>

So for examle 

<h1> Desciption 1 </>
 <p>Description 2 </p>
<h3> Descriptionn 3 </h3>
<p> Description 4 </p>

Comment: @Rinael see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
<div>
        {Object.keys(allDesc).map((desc, index) => {
          if (allDes[desc] !== "") {
            return (
              <>
                {
                 desc === 'description' ? <h1>allDes[desc]</h1> : 
                 <p>allDes[desc]</p>
                } 
              </>
            );
          }
        })}
      </div>
```

this `allDes[desc]` is have the value of all field you loop from the Object keys.